# Toggle 'required' property with jquery

Tags: jquery

Here's the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LEZ4r/77/

And the code itself:

```
<form action="demo_form.asp">
  <input type="text" name="first_name" value="" id="freeform_first_name"
    maxlength="150" required/>
  <div>
      Needs coupon? 
      <input type="radio" name="requires" value="yes">Yes</input>
      <input type="radio" name="requires" value="no" checked>No</input>
  </div>
        <div class="coupon" id="hidden">
            <input type="text" name="code"
            maxlength="150"/>
            </div>
        <input type="submit"/>
</form>

$(function(){
$('.coupon').toggle();  $('input:radio[name="requires"]').change(function() {
        var coup = $('.coupon');
        coup.toggle();
        if (coup.prop('required')) {
            coup.prop('required', false);
        } else {
            coup.prop('required', true);
        }
    });
});
```

When I check via the console in chrome, the required property is indeed set. When submitting the form though, it acts as though it's not. What's going wrong?

Comment: It would be impossible to answer this without the JSFiddle. Please include everything required to diagnose the problem *in the question itself*.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You're setting `required` on the `div` containing your `input`, not on the `input` itself.

You need to actually set `required` on the `input`:

```
coup.find('input').prop('required', true)
```